Does this picture come from a movie starring Arnold Schwarzenegger?
This picture shows Arnold Schwarzenegger surrounded by animals. Assuming this is not Photoshopped, which of his movies does this come from?


I’m voting to close this question because it's not even about identifying a movie but a random image from the internet.

After reverse image searching via TinEye, I believe that this image originates from the cover of the January 2009 edition of Intelligence in Lifestyle magazine, and not from any of Schwarzenegger's movies:


Just to add, this January 2009 magazine cover is featured among other worthy pages from the magazine, in a D&D Award winning entry for 2009 "Magazine & Newspaper Design" category.

This photo is not from a movie. It's from a 2009 edition of the italian magazine Intelligence in Lifestyle. The cover features Arnold Schwarzenegger sitting on a stone in the forest, surrounded by animals on the cover that are presumably stuffed or photoshopped in.

I wonder whether there are any credits to the photographers responsible for the elements of the final composited picture, maybe one photographer for the background, one or several for the animals, and one for Arnold?

It is photoshopped as a creation but it's not from a movie, it's an image from a tweet by Arnold in 2020.


He certainly posted it, but that doesn't seem to be where it's from.
